# Best way to get current route in Vue3 and Vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am trying to get the current path (something like `"https://example.com/some/path"`) with Vue3 and Vue-router.

Before, when using Vue2, I could get the current route using:

```js
    // works with vue 2.x with composition-api, but not with vue 3.x
    setup(_, ctx) {
        const path = computed(() => ctx.root.$route.path)
```

but in Vue3 it is not possible to use `ctx.root` ([as stated by Evan You here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1056)).
So what is the preferred way to get the current route with Vue3?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use composable function [`useRoute`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup) :

```
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'
import {computed} from 'vue'
...

setup(){
   const route=useRoute();

   const path = computed(() =>route.path)
}
```

Comment: How to do that in the options api?

Comment: @PetarVasilev you could use `this.$route.path`

Comment: I am trying to access this.$route.name but it is the same. `name` is always undefined even though in the global instance of `vue-router` current route is correct. `path` is always `/` even though I am on another page. Any ideas?

Comment: @PetarVasilev can you show how did you use it? and how did configure the router?

Comment: It turns out there was a problem with my computer when I restarted it started working.

Comment: Actually, there was another problem. `Vue router` was not ready. I had to wrap `application.mount('#app');` in `router.isReady().then(...)`

Comment: Please create a new question describing the issue and let me know

Comment: That solved it so no point in in question. Hopefully, people can find it here.