# How to check condition by route params in vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm making a Dashboard page (Using Vue3), the initial frame has a nav bar on the top and a menu bar on the right, and the router view for navigation will be at the bottom, it looks like this...
[image]

**Here is the code in views**

```js
<template>
  <div class="flex h-screen bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900" id="app">
    <Sidebar v-if="checklogin" :isSideMenuOpen="isSideMenuOpen" @close-side-menu="isSideMenuOpen = false" />

    <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 w-full">
      <Navigation v-if="checklogin" @open-side-menu="isSideMenuOpen = !isSideMenuOpen" />
      <div class="p-6 dark:text-white">
        <RouterView />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want when it's the login page it will hide the nav and the menu bar has to go so I'm catching the route params like this and it's clear that the value at the initial run time in the login page is correct but when I go to the new page it fails
**Here is the code for the logic part**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, watch} from "vue";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import "@/assets/main.min.css" 

import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'
import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue'


const isSideMenuOpen = ref(false);
const checklogin = ref(true);
const route = useRoute()
let pathName: any = route.matched[0].name
console.log("=>:",pathName) 
onMounted(()=>{
  if(pathName=='login'){
    checklogin.value = false
  }
  else{ 
    checklogin.value = true
 }
})
</script>
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

I'm using: VueJs ver3, Vite, TypeScript I've just switched to Vue3, so I don't know very well, looking forward to receiving guidance from the masters. ^^

Comment: Hi, it would be best if you elaborated on what is failing. The nav bar does not hide or is there any error? Anyway, you should get the current route [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989529/4254681)

Comment: @Duannx I edited and posted my error message

Comment: are you implement [Vue 3 Routing](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html#simple-routing-from-scratch)? if your router config for login page, you don't need check route name in login page.

Comment: The error shows that your `route.matched[0]` is `undefined`. You can get the route name just by `route.name`

Comment: @Henry Trần This is my login page router:     {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import('../views/Login.vue')
    },

Comment: I tried route.name and it returns undefined

Comment: From @Duannx answer: replace `route.matched[0].name` by `route.name`.

Comment: Try making a minimal reproduction of your problem on stackblitz.com

Comment: Shouldn't you use watchEffect instead of onMounted ?